# Make simple in-depth partial views with Code Igniter

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter, partial-views, codeigniter-2

I would like to embed views in a "deep" way:

**index.php:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?= contents_of('page') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**page.php:**

```
<div><?= contents_of('section') ?></div>
```

**section.php:**

```
<span>Hello</span>
```

That would output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use the [Contentful](https://github.com/shawndellysse/codeigniter-contentful) library for Codeigniter, which is quite close to the Rails template system, but I don't have any idea to embed with one more depth level.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I made my own library to handle what I needed:
https://github.com/ldiqual/codeigniter-pview

Thanks for your answers, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just `include` the files directly.

In CodeIgniter, all files are referenced from the main index.php, so your file paths will be from there.  Use `include` not `include_once` to include pages multiple times.  As long as you aren't creating functions or other unique items in views that could conflict when being included multiple times, you should be fine.

Example:

**MAIN View**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php include('application/views/page.php') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Page View**

```
<div><?php include('application/views/section.php') ?></div>
```

Comment: I'm calling `$this->load->view('section')` from the `section` method of my `page` controller. So there is no way to embed the `section` view in the `<div></div>` with your method.
Something that would be nice is a system when you have to declare a default partial-view by controller. So my `section` view would be called in the controller view, then in the main layout.

Comment: Only load the top level view from your controller and it will work.  It's just regular php.

Comment: OR you can pass a 3rd parameter to `$this->load->view('section', $data, true)` which will return a string that you can manipulate.  Do this for all views concatenating the results and echo it at the end.  But that won't give you multiple levels of depth.

Comment: Another problem with that is that I can't generate code for __different__ parts of the controller main view. That's what rail's `content_for` is meant for, but I can't see how to reproduce it here...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use (or write your own) some template library. The reason is, it will be difficult to manage and bind a data, in the way you did now. The idea of using a template library is to collect all your view file, then put them in each correct position respectively. Or, for manageable reason,i think re-design your recent view stucture schema, to two depth or less(with 'partial' view concept) will be your best bet.